# Create tablespace in postgresql and set is to it is the default for all newly created databases

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, tablespace

I have created a tablespace named `hdd_tablespace` and I wan't all new databases to be automatically created there. Basically when I execute:

```
CREATE DATABASE FOO;
```

I want this database to be created in `hdd_tablespace`.

I have updated `postgresql.conf` with:

```
 default_tablespace = 'hdd_tablespace'
```

However, new databases are still created in `pg_default`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it turned out I had also to update `template1` database that is a [template database](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html).

I had to;

```
ALTER DATABASE template1 SET TABLESPACE hdd_tablespace;
```